# String to UTF-32 string

Tags: swift, utf

I have gone through many questions here but none of them seems to work for me. I simply want to convert my string to UTF-32 string. Like shown in the image [image]

```
var str = "Your"

let dataenc = str.data(using: String.Encoding.utf32)

extension Data {
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%04hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

let data = str.data(using: .utf16)!
let hexString = data.map{ String(format:"%02x", $0) }.joined()

print(data.hexEncodedString())
print(hexString)
```

this doesn't work

the output I get is

> 00ff00fe00590000006f00000075000000720000
>
> fffe59006f0075007200

not sure what to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same result you need to use the `.utf32BigEndian` string encoding.

```
extension Data {
    func hexEncodedString() -> String {
        return map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
    }
}

var str = "Your"
let dataenc = str.data(using: .utf32BigEndian)!
print(dataenc.hexEncodedString())
```

Output:

> 000000590000006f0000007500000072

Note that when using just `.utf32` you get 20 bytes for the string "Your" but with `.utf32BigEndian` you only get 16 bytes for the same string. Those extra 4 bytes represent the "BOM" (byte order marker). In your case, the result of using `.utf32` gave you the data in "little-endian" format with the "BOM" at the start of the data. That's why the data started with the extra `00ff00fe` (the BOM) and each of the next 4 bytes appeared in the wrong order.

Explicitly stating `.utf32BigEndian` puts the bytes in the desired order and eliminates the BOM.

Comment: @rv7284 - In case you're curious I just updated my answer with an explanation of the output you received when using `.utf32` compared to the needed encoding of `.utf32BinEndian`.